# Trouble sizing custom cells in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have built a simple messenger using a Parse backend. In a `tableView`, i display a conversation between users. The cells in that `tableView` resize according to the amount of text on a label.

I am using this code in `viewDidLoad()` to achieve the resize:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 51
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.setNeedsLayout()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I use an estimated height of 51 because that is the height of my cell on storyboard.
Anyway, the problem I am facing is that sometimes the cells are not sized properly and will sometimes appear too big for the contents they hold. I cannot figure out why. This is an incorrect rendering of the cells[image: .]

This is a slightly more correct rendering of the cells I achieved by simply scrolling up and back down.

[image: .]

What's going on here?

Comment: Please look at this tutorial:
[UITableView Tutorial: Dynamic Table View Cell Height](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

Comment: Okay, so I looked at this tutorial and it gave me some insight as to what I might have been doing wrong, however, after following some of the advice provided, I am still facing the same exact problem where some cells just decide to be too big.. Thanks though @madmir, twas a good resource

Answer (score 0):

```
remove this lines from viewDidLoad

1)tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 51
2)tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

use below two methods of tableview

override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
{
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: This changes nothing, unfortunately.